# Which NPCs share my love of eating dead NPCs?

Tags: fallout-4

After butchering a couple dozen Raiders, my health was low & I started working up quite the appetite. So naturally, I decided to eat a few of the Raiders. However, my companion did not share my enthusiasm and very pretty disgusted by it.

Later that day, I saw one of my settlers get brutally murdered by a deathclaw. Since food is scarce in the wasteland, I decided to finish off what the deathclaw started (clearly, deathclaws are nature's quitters). However, the surviving settlers immediately turned hostile and I was forced to eat all of them too.

I'm noticing there is quite the social stigma associated with cannibalism. That being said, I was wondering are there any NPCs that don't mind if I eat a person every now and then?

Comment: Admit it, you just wrote this question for the title. :P

Comment: I am 93.5% sure this isn't a serious question and is more of a joke to make people lol or go eww. It made me lol so here take my up vote.

Comment: I cracked up laughing on the bus as soon as I saw "and I was forced to eat all of them too" and everyone was looking at me weirdly, haha

Comment: So.. are you asking **why** NPCs hate canabalism, or which NPC is OK with it? Your asking two differant questions, and as a result, have recieved two differant answers.

Comment: Wish I could give bounties to questions...

Comment: @Timelord64 sorry for being vague, I'm curious about what NPCs are accepting of my life choices. Hate having companions that judge my every move. If it were up to me, I'd eat them too...

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Strong not only doesn't mind the Sole Survior feasting on the flesh of his/her enemies, but approves. And Dogmeat, of course, loves you anyway.

In general, humans and ghouls are disgusted, and robots and synths don't care either way.